# How to store images (besides data) faster and with reduced size in a file

Tags: python, json, image, numpy, file

I want to store numpyarrays(images), data and a timestamp to a file in Python.
Later i want to scroll through the images and show the data.

I wrote my data to a json file, but it takes long and with one image(640x480) and one set of data it gets 10 Mb in size.

Here is my aproach:

```
import json as json
import base64
import io
import sys
import cv2

import numpy as np

import os

from numpy import asarray
from json import JSONEncoder

path = r'C:/Videotool/Data'
name = 'testfile'


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
result, image = cam.read()

if result:
    print(f'image:{image}')
else:
    print('no image')



def json_write_to_file(path, name, data):
        file_exists = os.path.exists(name+'.json')
        file = path + '/' + name + '.json'
        readed_data = []
        data_list = []
        sum_dict = []
        if file_exists:
            print(f'file {name}.json exist\n')
            with open(file) as fp:
                readed_data = json.load(fp)
            print(f'readed_data:{readed_data}\n')
            
            print(f'data:{data}\n')

            readed_data.append(data)
            sum_dict = readed_data

            print(f'sum_dict:{sum_dict}\n')
            with open (file, 'w') as fp:
                json.dump(sum_dict, fp, indent=2)
                print(f'length of readed_data: {len(readed_data)}\n')
                #fp.write('\n')
        else:
            sum_dict.append(data)
            print(f'file {name}.json not exists\n')    
            with open (file, 'w') as fp:
                json.dump(sum_dict, fp, indent=2)


print(f'Number of Dimensions of image:{image.ndim}')
print(f'Shape of image:{image.shape}')
print(f'Size of image:{image.size}')

low_image_array = image.reshape(-1)

ori_array = np.zeros((2,3,4))

print(f'Number of Dimensions of ori_array:{ori_array.ndim}')
print(f'Shape of ori_array:{ori_array.shape}')
print(f'Size of ori_array:{ori_array.size}')

print(f'ori_array:{ori_array}')

low_1_array = ori_array.reshape(-1)


print(f'Number of Dimensions of low_1_array:{low_1_array.ndim}')
print(f'Shape of low_1_array:{low_1_array.shape}')
print(f'Size of low_1_array:{low_1_array.size}')

print(f'low_1_array:{low_1_array}')

data_set = {}
data_set['Stream_1']    = low_1_array.tolist()
data_set['Stream_2']    = low_image_array.tolist()

print(f'data_set: {data_set}')

json_write_to_file(path, name, data_set)
```

Is there a better way to store images and data in a file?

Comment: You can use `numpy.save` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) or save images with `python-opencv` as png/jpg.

Comment: I would like to get the Images and the Data in one File. If i am right, np.save creates single Files per Image. Or do i miss something?

Comment: You are right - it saves only image data. You can for example save image in `file123.npy` and additional data in `file123.json`.

Comment: I need to save a big series of images (videostream) with coresponding data. Thats why i am looking for a way to put everything in one file. The JSON approach does that, but extremely slow. The minimum would be getting all Images in order in one file i think. I dont like the idea of using a Videofile and sync the data to it....

Comment: I think saving it as video file would be the most memory efficient way (as it is optimized for that). How about saving it as some `mp4` file and additional data in one json with frame number for each entry?

Comment: You could also look into using Parquet files with compression: https://parquet.apache.org/

Comment: I will look into parquet! The mp4 + json file will be my fall back solution :) I really wish to get everything in one file ...